# VSCode Multiple Projects Reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I'm having a little bit of problem with VSCode creating C# program and multiple folder structure.

For example, I have a folder call SampleProject1 (I consider a folder project maybe I'm wrong) in this folder I have my Program class that has the entry point for my test application, in the main method of the Program class I'm referencing a Test class that lives in a second folder call SampleProject2, but when I run the program I get an error that my test class does not exist.

Things that I try do far.

1. I tried to add SampleProject2 as a dependency on the project.json for SampleProject1  but that did not work.
2. I run the dotnet pack for SampleProject 2 and added as a dependency on the project.json for SampleProject1 and that also fail.
3. I also try to run"yo aspnet" command to create csproj but I think is no longer valid see link [here](https://isimplecoder.github.io/2015/05/04/debugc%23/)
4. I went to VSCode GitHUb and did not find a test real C# example (weird)

project.json on SampleProject1

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {

  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Program.cs on SampleProject1

```
using System;
using SampleProject2;

namespace SampleProject1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new TestClass();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

project.json on SampleProject2

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

TestClass.cs on SampleProject2

```
namespace SampleProject2
{

    public class TestClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

}
```

UPDATE:
I was able to compile the application by setting the folder on the root of the project. But I don't get intelesense

VSCode Extructure [image]

Compilation Error Command Pront [image]

Comment: check VS Code Multiple project documentation http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vscode/7717/multiple-projects-set-up#t=201611030739421019893

Answer (score 1):

C# projects are not yet supported by VSCode. See github response [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10929) and the intellisense problem is answer [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10929)

Answer (score 0):

I cant see the error from the screenshot as its truncated (can you copy and paste the error rather than screenshot it?), but you've declared `TestClass()` but are trying to instantiate `TesClass()`, so it looks like a simple typo to me here...

Answer (score 0):

To build the solution with multiple projects add a dependency for the external library inside `SampleProject1/project.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "SampleProject2": "1.0.0-*"
  },
```

Then to enable IntelliSense use OmniSharp [feature](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/713) for toggling between multiple projects.

Since SampleProject1 depends on SamleProject2, the best way is to direct OnmiSharp engine on the both projects (root). Click `Select project` and choose what is best fits you.

[image]
[image]